# Android access attribute reference

Tags: android

In the Android resources xml to reference the value of an attribute for a theme you use the question-mark (?) instead of at (@). Such as ListViewCustomStyle below:

```
 <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/MainScreenListView" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="?ListViewCustomStyle"/>
```

How can I use the value of the ListViewCustomStyle in code? If I try it the normal way i.e.

```
com.myapp.R.attr.ListViewCustomStyle
```

Then the code crashes. Is there a special way to access this since it is a reference to an item and not an actual item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might just be crashing because you wrote ListRowCustomStyle there, and ListViewCustomStyle in your xml.

The way I do this is to have the tag style="@style/my_button" for example (with no android: preceding it). Then you can define your style in the values/styles.xml file, e.g.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="my_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    ...
       </style>
</resources>
```

You can access the style in code by using the id R.style.my_button

Comment: Woops ListRowCustomStyle was a typo; I have fixed

Answer (score 2):

I believe in the xml you wanted to write

**style="@style/ListViewCustomStyle"**

Anyway, how to use it in code?

Last time I check, it was impossible :(

I did it with a trick:

1. create a layout file as the example that follows:

   ```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyCustomStyle"/>
   ```
2. when you want to add an object with your custom style in code, you have to inflate it, using this layout you just created:

:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); // this = activity or context
Button button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myButtonWithMyStyle, null); //use the same layout file as above
button.setText("It works!");
myView.addView(button);
```

This is considerably slower than creating a Button in code. It may be a problem if you create hundreads of Views at the same time using this method. Less than that I think you can handle it.

Comment: Ok, now it's showing everything (there was some bug that was hidding some of the code)